# Adding proper spacing when scraping html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping the content of a series of html pages, but am having a problem with beautifulsoup squishing together text when it is grabbing from certain tags. Below is a specific example of the problem I am running into and contains the html and then the text from this [webpage](http://www.bclaws.ca/civix/document/id/loo103/loo103/337_95). As you can see the html prints the numbers `2` and `2.1` without spacing. And this is reflected when I run

```
text = soup.find("div", {"id":"contentsscroll"}).text
```

or something similar that grabs the text. In essence I need a way to insert spacing when ever I run into the `<strong>` tag or a similar method. I am also fine with just completely ignoring the numbering if there is a way to ignore that tag. The main issue I am trying to avoid is the squishing of numbers with text for future text analysis purposes.

`<div class="section"><h4><a name="section2"></a>Repealed</h4><p id="d2e64" class="sec1"><span class="secno"><strong>2</strong></span>&nbsp; Repealed. [B.C. Reg. 277/2000, s. 2.]</p></div><div class="section">
    <h4>
        <a name="section2.1"></a>Elizabeth Bagshaw Society</h4><p id="d2e76" class="sec1d1"><span class="secno"><strong>2.1</strong></span>&nbsp; Subject to section 5 (3) of the <em>Access to Abortion
            Services Act</em>, the access zone for the facility operated by the
        Elizabeth Bagshaw Society at 1177 West Broadway in the City of Vancouver is established as
        the area within the heavy outline shown on the plan in Appendix&nbsp;2.1.</p>`

Repealed**2**  Repealed. [B.C. Reg. 277/2000, s. 2.]

Elizabeth Bagshaw Society**2.1**  Subject to section 5 (3) of the *Access to Abortion
            Services Act*, the access zone for the facility operated by the
        Elizabeth Bagshaw Society at 1177 West Broadway in the City of Vancouver is established as
        the area within the heavy outline shown on the plan in Appendix 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `.text` property, use the `.get_text()` method and pass a space as an argument. BeautifulSoup will join together each piece of text with a space, rather than pushing the text together.

So replace:

`text = soup.find("div", {"id":"contentsscroll"}).text`

with:

`text = soup.find("div", {"id":"contentsscroll"}).get_text(" ")`.

You can then remove any unwanted multiple spaces using `re.sub(r" +", " ", text)`.